Write out the peak memory utilization of a Pyspark Job on EMR to a file
We run a lot of Pyspark jobs on EMR. The pipeline executed is the same, but the inputs can wildly change the peak memory utilization, and that utilization is growing over time. I would like to automatically write out the peak memory utilization of each step submitted to the EMR cluster -- effectively, "you used 10TBs of RAM at the peak of usage" (yes this is common for our jobs). Our jobs are not throttled by CPU or any other metric, memory is all I care about, though if writing out all the aggregate metrics simplifies the approach I'm open to it.
If it matters, we are using cluster mode with yarn as the cluster manager. We are also submitting these jobs as Docker containers.
I have tried the following two approaches, but I am very open to the idea that I'm wildly overthinking this... it doesn't feel like it should be that hard to just do:
spark = init_spark()

do_some_stuff()

spark.metrics.peakMemoryUtilization()


So if I'm missing something please educate me.
Attempt 1 - Custom Class extending JVM's Spark Listener
Fiddling with some suggestions from Github CoPilot (I know) I was pointed towards using SparkListeners for this task, however I have not had any success with this approach. The suggested approach appears to be to create a custom class which uses the JVM's access to the tasks.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import

class MemoryUsageListener:
    def __init__(self):
        self.peak_memory_usage = 0

    def on_task_end(self, task_end):
        metrics = task_end.taskMetrics()
        memory_used = metrics.peakExecutionMemory()
        if memory_used > self.peak_memory_usage:
            self.peak_memory_usage = memory_used

    # Getter function for adding this to the SparkContext's Listeners
    def get_listener(self, sc):
        gw = sc._gateway
        java_import(gw.jvm, "org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener")
        java_import(gw.jvm, "org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerTaskEnd")

        class JavaListener(gw.jvm.SparkListener):
            def __init__(self, parent):
                super(gw.jvm.SparkListener, self).__init__()
                self.parent = parent

            def onTaskEnd(self, taskEnd):
                self.parent.on_task_end(taskEnd)

        return JavaListener(self)

    def get_peak_memory_usage(self):
        return self.peak_memory_usage

With the setup being something like:
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("MemoryUsageTracker")
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

# Create and register the listener
memory_listener = MemoryUsageListener()
java_listener = memory_listener.get_listener(sc)
sc._jsc.sc().addSparkListener(java_listener)

... do some spark stuff here (run the actual job) ...

peak_memory_usage = memory_listener.get_peak_memory_usage()
write_to_file(peak_memory_usage)


I played with the above suggestion extensively but struggled with the following: JavaClass.__init__() "takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given" when the class is initialized, specifically it hates class JavaListener(gw.jvm.SparkListener). I've tried moving the super declaration around, moving the Java class into a completely separate function, no cigar. It seems intuitive, but clearly I don't understand how this OOP approach works unfortunately.
Attempt 2 - API Calls to Yarn
Okay, so the intuitive solution of just asking Spark what it's doing didn't work. Another suggestion I found was to use the requests library and hit the api endpoint to get details on the executors.
import requests
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf

def get_executor_memory_metrics(app_id, spark_history_server_url):
    response = requests.get(f"{spark_history_server_url}/api/v1/applications/{app_id}/executors")
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to fetch executor metrics, status code: {response.status_code}")
    executors = response.json()
    return executors

def calculate_peak_memory_usage(executors):
    # i'm not certain this is the correct dict access, it's what copilot generated, but it's not my current issue
    peak_memory_usage = max(executor['peakMemoryMetrics']['JVMHeapMemory'] for executor in executors if 'peakMemoryMetrics' in executor)
    return peak_memory_usage

sc = spark.sparkContext
app_id = sc.applicationId

master_url = sc.master
# I'm not convinced this logic is actually sound, but I don't have access to modify the cluster / yarn settings. 
yarn_resource_manager_host = socket.getfqdn()
yarn_port = 18080

# At the end of the job
executors = get_executor_memory_metrics(app_id, f"{yarn_resource_manager_host}:{yarn_port}")
peak_memory_usage = calculate_peak_memory_usage(executors)

And obviously the above code would be packaged in a thread to loop and continuously monitor the peak usage -- however, before moving to that piece, I'm unable to get the request portion actually working with a persistent "Connection Refused" error. I've confirmed it's receiving the cluster's IP and application id correctly and imputing the URL, though I can't share them here -- I'm not certain the port number is right, but I'm not sure if there's a better way to access it at runtime.

Where you able to advance this?

This may take some back and forth but for 500 i am willing to help.
Have you tried mining JMX information? remember to enable JMX and specify it in -D parameters
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=600

Don't code anything, just use some generic JMX client.
Once that is working review stats for per-job details... not sure those are given, I will try to review your comments here

Did you find any useful metric in CloudWatch? Regarding memory utilization over EMR cluster and/or Steps? Do you separate pipelines into different clusters or run everything in a single?
You might also consider of exposing spark metrics into Prometheus (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-Serverless-UserGuide/monitor-with-prometheus.html)
and aggregate over multiple metrics (jvm memory / spark job or task ids) to calculate peak utilization info.
Though if you don't have Grafana or any other monitoring app this might be a big leap towards observability, but at the same time to much time consuming to establish while you only need the metric printed out into std.

Creating custom SparkListener in Scala or Java would be pretty straightforward, but since you seem to be favoring pyspark, perhaps you can get this info from Spark Event logs? This might be accomplished in two steps:

For your application(s), enable executor metrics logging at stage boundary --conf spark.eventLog.logStageExecutorMetrics=true. (You may also want to enable logging of the OS level memory metrics by adding --conf spark.executor.processTreeMetrics.enabled). For example:

$ pyspark --conf spark.eventLog.logStageExecutorMetrics=true --conf spark.executor.processTreeMetrics=true
:
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import *
>>> spark.range(1,1000000) \
      .withColumn("spark_partition",spark_partition_id()) \
      .groupby("spark_partition") \
      .count().show(truncate=False)
+---------------+------+
|spark_partition|count |
+---------------+------+
|1              |500000|
|0              |499999|
+---------------+------+


Upon application completion, parse out executor memory metrics from the Event log. For example, using pyspark itself

>>> df = spark.read.json("/user/spark/applicationHistory/application_9999999999999_9999")
>>> df.where("Event = 'SparkListenerStageExecutorMetrics'") \
      .select("Stage ID", "`Executor Metrics`.JVMHeapMemory", \
              "`Executor Metrics`.JVMOffHeapMemory", \
              "`Executor Metrics`.OnHeapUnifiedMemory", \
              "`Executor Metrics`.OffHeapUnifiedMemory") \
      .show(truncate=False)
+--------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|Stage ID|JVMHeapMemory|JVMOffHeapMemory|OnHeapUnifiedMemory|OffHeapUnifiedMemory|
+--------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|0       |0            |0               |0                  |0                   |
|0       |316247800    |167633296       |50550              |0                   |
|:       |      :      |       :        |       :           |        :           |
+--------+-------------+----------------+-------------------+--------------------+

